# Erro valores props vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

No `console` do navegador mostra esse aviso toda vez que seleciona uma `data` no campo do formulário, como faço para resolver ? Eu defini um componente `pai form` completo separado eu chamo no `formfilho` em outro componente.

**Obs:** Está cadastrando normalmente só esse aviso que aparece no console, quando seleciona as datas nos campos datavalidade e dataExpedicao.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O erro caso a imagem não apareça:** *[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "dataExpedicao"
found in.*

**Pedaço do Código html que está ocorrendo o aviso no console**

```
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <label class="form-control-label">Data de Expedição *</label>
  <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
          </div>
        <my-date-picker v-validate="'required'" v-model="dataExpedicao"
                    @input="$emit('update:dataExpedicao', dataExpedicao)" name="data de expedição">
        </my-date-picker>
  </div>
    <small class="text-danger"
           v-show="errors.has('data de expedição')">{{ errors.first('data de expedição') }}</small>
  </div>


<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
   <label class="form-control-label">Data de Validade *</label>
  <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
      </div>
        <my-date-picker v-validate="'required'" v-model="dataValidade"
                        @input="$emit('update:dataValidade', dataValidade)" name="data de validade">
        </my-date-picker>
  </div>
  <small class="text-danger"
         v-show="errors.has('data de validade')">{{ errors.first('data de validade') }}</small>
 </div>
```

**Props no componente pai estou passando corretamente.**

```
 props: ['dataExpedicao', .....],
```

**No form filho(cadastro) chamo os dados do componente pai**

```
 <FormFilho :dataExpedicao.sync="licenca.dataExpedicao" .....>
  </FormFilho>



<script>
import FormFilho from './FormFilho';

export default {

    data() {
        return {
            licenca: {
                dataExpedicao: '',
                .......
                .......
            }
        }
    },
</script>
```